# Как убрать ошибку 500?

Tags: php, http, guzzle

делаю `GET` запрос на сторонний сервис с параметрами через `GUZZLE`, в итоге выдаёт ошибку:

Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException: Server error: `GET resulted in a` 500 Internal Server Error

Но ответ от сервера приходит корректный, как починить?
Пробовал через `try catch`, ловить ошибку в `catch` и оттуда уже вытаскивать ответ, но мне кажется это костыльно.
Сервер поднимаю на `openserver.`

код:

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

if (isset($_POST['city'])) {
  $response  = $client->request('GET', url, [
    'query' => ['city' => $_POST['city'], 'weight' => $_POST['weight']]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй просмотреть логи OpenServer.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]